# a value of type "locatime_s" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "tm*"

Tags: visual-c++

I would like know how I can fix this code, the conflict seems between 
"locatime_s or localtime_r with time_t and tm*. I tried to use localtime, 
but it generate the error "localtime is a unsafed function, try to use 
localtime_r or localtime_s.

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <time.h>       
#include <locale.h>    

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];

  struct lconv * lc;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

  int twice=0;

  do {
    printf ("Locale is: %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL) );

    strftime (buffer,80,"%c",timeinfo);
    printf ("Date is: %s\n",buffer);

    lc = localeconv ();
    printf ("Currency symbol is: %s\n-\n",lc->currency_symbol);

    setlocale (LC_ALL,"");
  } while (!twice++);

  return 0;
}
```

This code would should show the locate, the date, the Currenty symbol, 
and moreover change the locale and the Currenty symbol.

Comment: `localtime_s` takes two parameters, not one; and returns `errno_t`, not `struct tm*`

Comment: Please paste code snippet here, do not use screenshots

Comment: I tryed to pass the code, but I wasn't allowed, since it is my first post here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code, the code is working in Visual Studio 2019. Thanks for who help with your comments and I wish that this post can help another people.

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <time.h>       
#include <locale.h>    

int main()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm timeinfo;
    char buffer[40];
    errno_t err;
    struct lconv* lc;

    time(&rawtime);  //Gets the current time.
    err = localtime_s(&timeinfo,&rawtime);

    int twice = 0;

    do {
        printf("Locale is: %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL));

        strftime(buffer, 40, "%c", &timeinfo);
        printf("Date is: %s\n", buffer);

        lc = localeconv();
        printf("Currency symbol is: %s\n-\n", lc->currency_symbol);

        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    }     while (!twice++);
}
```